# HTML Column Rearrangement with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a picture column on the left side, and a navigation column on the right side and a flexible width central column which is the content.

edit: These columns are all DIVS

**Current:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
|              |                   |               |
| Column left  |   Centre Column   | Column right  |
|   (305px)    |                   |    (250px)    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

The left and right columns have fixed widths and the centre column fills the space.

What I am trying to find out is how to make this layout rearrange for mobile viewing on taller narrow devices, I intend (due to the relative narrowness of the left and right columns) to rearrange that on CSS widths of less than ~850px, the layout becomes:

**Intended:**

```
----------------------------------
|                 |              |
| Column left     | Column right |
|   (305px)       |   (250px)    |
----------------------------------
|                                |
|          Centre Column         |
|              (100%)            |
----------------------------------
```

Centred in the screen space.

(And on very narrow screens this is further stacked as:

```
----------
|  Left  |
----------
| centre |
----------
|  Right |
----------
```

)

Currently the left and right columns are floats around the centre, So what I am asking is how can (or should) I approach media specific CSS rules to turn the left and right floats to appear as above?

I would like to do this *if possible* without changing the HTML on the page (there are many pages to work on). I can't use `flexbox` as this needs to be as backward compatible as possible.

There are probably many answers already on SO for this but I can't find them, maybe due to searching the wrong descriptions, terminology, etc. Answers I have already found all seem to be based on the columns all being a static known width, whereas the central column is a filler width of `(100% - left column - right column)`.

**Edits/clarifiers:**

- I am using media queries but I am asking the question of to what I can put in the media queries to get the desired results.
- Due to reading that IE10 has issues with `flexbox` and long paragraphs (and other minor issues too) I am cautious about using flexbox.
- The current layout uses HTML div elements. No tables.
- The centre column is text heavy and is of variable width, the other two columns are static widths (left:305, right:250) and theses can not change.

Comment: And the HTML is.... ???? Is different making with divs or with tables

Comment: And consider using new technologies. Make a web responsive to IE7 is a crap of javascript to workaround and hack. EDIT: I not downvote you, there are many people that is the only that he makes, downvote :(

Comment: I edited the question, the columns are all divs. Which new technologies should I use? flexbox is not comfortable with IE10 and I'm specifically required to make this as backwardly compatible as reasonably possible. @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: hi can you show your html code and try so it would be easier for us to try for your problem's solution

Comment: @Martin ok, because you need media queries to make it and IE10 is able to do it.

Comment: @Martin This setup is only possible by moving the columns around as this kind of different squashing won't work because of document flow. Please add proper html code and your current CSS (if possible) and what you tried. For IE7 users there is _no need to support multiple styles_. IE7 is never a mobile browser and users of old IEs are not at all expecting your site to be responsive anyhow.

Comment: @somethinghere I don't get the reference to IE7? I have updated my question with edit notes at the bottom

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes I will be using media queries to get the desired results at different screen sizes, I have updated my question. cheers.

Comment: You can view my answer, I think that solves your problem. Good luck

Comment: @Martin I will reiterate: this kind of setup is not possible within modifying your dom.Your content flow is as follows: `desktop { left > middle > right } tablet { left > right > middle} mobile { left > middle > right }`. Because of this flow it will be very hard to make this work correctly, and the end result won't be pretty.

Comment: @somethinghere that is what I was expected, I was hoping there may be a CSS sidestep to work around this, basically a `flexbox` in another form. cheers. I'm using `flexbox` and it's results are adequate.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to finf d a solution but couldn't. For older browsers i would simply give your wrapoer a min-width so the site doesn't screw up.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need media queries in CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .left,.right { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
  .centre { display: block; width: 100%; clear: both; }
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .left,.right, .centre{ display: block; width: 100%; clear: both; }
}
```

This is to <900 pixels left and right and down centre. To <600 pixels all is vertical

Comment: cheers for that answer, but it persisted in stacking without causing the `.left` and `.right` to be inline. I will sort out the CSS and post up the code I have, later, but I'll probably just sod the compatibility and use `flexbox` :-/

Comment: Is inline-block, not only inline